# Is there an easy way to view Gitlab-CI artifacts?

Tags: gitlab-ci

We're migrating our CI from Phabricator/Jenkins to Gitlab and the UX for viewing docs is really not very good. The current workflow from the Merge Request page is

> Click build icon > click stage (e.g. build docs) > click Browse button under Job artifacts > click docs directory > click _build directory > click html directory > click index.html link

Seven clicks in all. With Phabricator, the Jenkins bot used to comment in the MR with a link to the docs page, so you could view the docs with a single click. Is there a way to do this with Gitlab?

(I would also like to do the same for coverage and lint reports, but will ask those questions separately, unless anyone has an easy solution that could be applied to all three types of artifact.)

Comment: I am also looking for same. Its a lot of clicks.

Comment: Someone has requested the same thing for coverage reports, but... *tumbleweed*. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/217998

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#access-the-latest-job-artifacts-by-url :

> To browse the latest job artifacts:
>
> ```
> https://example.com/<namespace>/<project>/-/jobs/artifacts/<ref>/browse?job=<job_name>
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/jobs/artifacts/main/browse?job=coverage
> ```

For example:

```
https://gitlab.com/<namespace>/<yourrepo>/-/jobs/artifacts/master/file/docs/_build/html/index.html?job=build_docs
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. While the explanation of the different parts of the URL is useful, it does not show how to reach it with one click from a merge request page.

Answer (score 1):

This has evolved again, with [GitLab 16.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/06/22/gitlab-16-1-released/#manage-job-artifacts-through-the-artifacts-page) (June 2023)

> ### Manage job artifacts through the Artifacts page
>
> Previously, if you wanted to view or manage job artifacts, you had to go to each job’s detail page, or use the API. Now, you can view and manage job artifacts through the **Artifacts** page accessed at **Build > Artifacts**.
>
> Users with at least the Maintainer role can use this new interface to delete artifacts too. You can delete individual artifacts, or bulk delete up to 100 artifacts at a time through either manual selection or checking the **Select all** option at the top of the page.
>
> Please use the survey at the top of the Artifacts page to share any feedback you have about this new functionality. To view additional UI features under consideration, you can check out the [Build Artifacts page enhancements epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/8311).
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_1/artifacts-bulk-delete.png -- Manage job artifacts through the Artifacts page]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_artifacts.html#view-all-job-artifacts-in-a-project), [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/33418), [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/370150), [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/33348) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/396792).

Comment: This also does not answer my question. From the artifacts page, it is six clicks to get to the built docs. We've actually written our own script that gets a bot to comment on the MR with a link to the docs. Now we can reach the docs in one click.

Comment: @jon_two interesting. Did you publish that bot script anywhere public?

Comment: Not yet, but we'll see if we can share it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`artifacts:expose_as`](https://docs.gitlab.com/16.8/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#artifactsexpose_as), which links the created artifacts in a [section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2Q7q.png) below the most recent pipeline status on the MR overview page.

Example job:

```yaml
job:
  image: alpine:latest
  script:
    - echo foo > bar.txt
  artifacts:
    expose_as: 'Job Report'
    paths: 
      - 'bar.txt'
```

Common coverage and lint reports can be included with [`artifacts:reports`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#artifactsreports).

Another option is to make use of the predictable URL pattern, as described by @KamilCuk, with [`environment:url`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#environmenturl). Here is an example to expose storybook:

```yaml
storybook:
  extends: .storybook_build
  environment:
    name: storybook-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    url: 'https://<org>.gitlab.io/-/<path>/<project>/-/jobs/$CI_JOB_ID/artifacts/storybook/index.html'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - 'storybook/'
    expire_in: 4 weeks
  allow_failure: true
```

This is just one click away from the MR page.

Comment: Thanks, we're already using `expose_as`. It doesn't help. How many clicks is it to get from the MR to the coverage report?

Comment: Some information is directly part of the MR overview and the full report is one click away, the caveat is that it is gitlab's own presentation and not just any custom report.

Comment: Ok, we've got a couple of subfolders in our paths list, so that's 2 clicks, but even if index.html was on the first page after you click on the artifacts, there are still two more clicks because "you are being redirected away from Gitlab".

Comment: Yeah it is all not the best experience. We actually now made it work for with an environment url link, added an example from a storybook job to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This has been added: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_artifacts.html#view-all-job-artifacts-in-a-project

> You can view all artifacts stored in a project from the CI/CD > Artifacts page. This list displays all jobs and their associated artifacts.

It is currently behind a feature flag (`artifacts_management_page`) and will be enabled be default in version 16.

Comment: This does make it easier to find artifacts for a project, but it's harder to see them when you are looking at an individual merge request. I tried it and it's 8 clicks, so is actually worse than the existing UI.